# binding toggles settings in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I created a component which is responsibility on user boolean settings,
I created a list of toggles, and their default values are taken from DB.
I meet a difficult when I tried to get the EDITED toggles to the TS file (from HTML)
what should I do:

````
<div class="container" dir="rtl" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col tb-text" >
        msg Type
      </div>
      <div class="col tb-text">
        send email notification ?
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of notificationsData">
        <div class="row tb-text">
            <div class="col">
              {{ item.NotificationMsgID}} 
              {{ item.NotificationMsgDescription}} 
            </div>
            <div class="col tb-text">
              {{ item.MailIsOn}} 
              <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{item.NotificationMsgID}}" [checked]=item.MailIsOn>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{item.NotificationMsgID}}"></label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <button class="tb-button btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="OnSubmit()"> SAVE settings </button>
    </div>```

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the element the user clicked on and sends it to the .ts component you must have pass it to some method in your .ts, in the example you can add a button inside the *ngFor and pass the item to the method.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of notificationsData">
<div class="row tb-text">
  <div class="col">
    {{ item.NotificationMsgID}} 
    {{ item.NotificationMsgDescription}} 
  </div>
  <div class="col tb-text">
    {{ item.MailIsOn}} 
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{item.NotificationMsgID}}" [checked]=item.MailIsOn>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{item.NotificationMsgID}}"></label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Add this button -->
  <button 
    type="button"
    class="tb-button btn btn-primary btn-block" 
    (click)="doSomething(item)"> 
      DO Something
  </button>
</div>
```

and in your .ts component you can receive this as:

```
doSomething(item: any): void {
    // Use item here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Riya

You can add a funcion on your `.ts` that will handle any change you make in your checkbox (toggle).

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{item.NotificationMsgID}}" 
[checked]=item.MailIsOn (change)="checkValue(item)">
```

So you have here to add the function that hadle your change in you .ts file

for examle:

```
checkValue(item){
  item.MailIsOn= !item.MailIsOn
}
```